# Writing theater play based on a movie (translated)

Tags: copyright

I am written a theater play based on a hollywood movie. I am from Bulgaria so I have wrote my play based on a transaction from the original movie script. My question is to whom I have to write if I want to buy the copyrights for my play. To the original movie owners of the rights or to the owners of the rights which are based in Bulgaria, because I have translated the script to Bulgaria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a derivate of a derivate. The Movie is based on a copyrighted script and in itself copyrighted.

Unless you have obtained a **license** for the making of the derivate, you violate the copyright in both the movie and the original script. Claiming fair use in such a case is very hard, so it would be very beneficial to try to obtain a license. The only one who can grant such a license is the owner of the original copyright, which is either the author of the original script or the material it is based on or whoever those did transfer their rights to. The translations have a separate copyright and might require another license.

Contact a copyright lawyer in your area.